# Beta functions of O$(N)$ model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, renormalization

Consider the O$(N)$ model in $d$-dimensions given by:

$$L = \frac{1}{2} (\partial_{\mu} \phi)^2 - \sum_{n} \frac{g_{2n}}{(2n)!} \phi^{2n} $$

Is there a reference where the beta functions $(\beta_{g_{2i}})$ of this model is calculated for general $n$, in general $d$? In particular, I wanted to verify my beta functions for $g_6$ and $g_8$.

Comment: For generic values of $n$ and $d$, the beta functions will be dominated by the classical terms $\beta_{2n} = [(n - 1)d - 2n]g_{2n} + O(g^2)$. We need to be in a special case satisfying $|(n - 1)d - 2n| \ll 1$ for the quantum $O(g^2)$ terms to be important. That is unless the couplings are large enough to make a perturbative analysis useless anyway.