# Resources on calculation of beta function for $\mathrm{O}(N)$ model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, renormalization, large-n

Is there any useful introductory material about the calculation of the beta function in $\phi^4$ scalar theory and $O(N)$ model? I would also like to generalize this to the large-$N$ limit.

Comment: Related, but unanswered: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/578643

Comment: You can write a few line long code in Mathematica, it's fairly simple then you can set your $N$, however since I was running the code in a 10 years old pc I couldn't go beyond $N=20$.

Comment: That sounds like a strange approach. The residue of $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ in the dimensionally regularized 4pt function of $\phi^i$ is an analytic function of $N$. If you want $\frac{1}{N}$ to be the expansion parameter instead of $\epsilon$, have a look at 1404.1094.